# PySpark dataframe column validation of a custom string column containing 1 of several possible two character codes

Tags: python, lambda, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a large pyspark dataframe. It has multiple columns of type string. I am casting those columns to the intended data types. All seems straight forward except a column that represents a company internal set of two character codes. I need to validate the column (in the set) and replace it with null if it is not valid. Here's what I have done so far:

```
myDfTyped = myDf.select(  myDf.EmployeeKey
, myDf["Amount"].cast("Decimal(10,4)")
, myDf["CountOfDays"].cast("Integer")
, myDf.select('specialCode')
)
```

The special code column represent a set of possible two character codes ('ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh')
I need to validate that the column contains one of these codes or put a null in that column. Replacing the value with a null matches what is expected if a cast doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

#sample data
specialCode = ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh']
df = sc.parallelize([
    ['ab', 10, 1],
    ['cd', 20, 2],
    ['ce', 30, 3],
    ['ef',  0, 4]
]).toDF(['EmployeeKey','Amount','CountOfDays'])

def intersect(val):
    return val if val in specialCode else None
intersectUDF = udf(intersect, StringType())
df = df.withColumn("EmployeeKey_converted", intersectUDF(df.EmployeeKey)).drop("EmployeeKey")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create UDF in Spark

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf



def exist(code):
   if code in codes:
        return code
   else:
       return null
codes = ['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh']

sqlContext.udf.register("check_code_exists", exist)


data = [{'amount':100,"code":'ab'},{'amount':500,"code":'vb'}]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data)

exist_udf = udf(exist)
df.select('code',exist_udf("code")).show()
```

Output :

```
+----+-----------+
|code|exist(code)|
+----+-----------+
|  ab|         ab|
|  vb|       null|
+----+-----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Steer away from User Defined Functions and use `isin`:

```
df.where(df["specialCode"].isin(['ab', 'cd', 'ef', 'gh']))
```